# Python regex remove string

Tags: python, regex

I have records in my text witch start with `PHOTO` and ends with `\n` how can I remove this text with regular expression.

Comment: Do you really need a regular expression?

Comment: Remove what text from which? Show the text before you run the code and the text that you want after you run the code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am putting down a couple of ways of doing it.

Slice the string:

```
>>> string = "PHOTOThe text which should be present\n"
>>> string[5:-1]
'The text which should be present'
```

Using regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> match = re.match("PHOTO(.+)\n", string)
>>> match.groups()
('The text which should be present',)
```

Comment: +1 from me because it also answers the original question :)

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't a regular expression, but what about

```
x = x[5:-1]
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
re.sub('^PHOTO.*\n', '', <your_string>)
```